# is there a way to connect an old luis.ai authoring resource to a newly created one?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer, azure-language-understanding

When using Composer for the first time I created an app in luis and connected from Composer to the Luis app with the key.

In Azure the luis resources were created - (when the resources are created in Azure there is  a resource-instance and resource-instance-authoring created, not sure the difference between the two).

[image]

[image]

I then wrote the bot in Composer.

After finishing the bot in Composer I let Composer publish and provision the Bot in Azure in a new resource group. It did this successfully.

When it publishes to Azure it creates a new luis instance and instance-authoring in the newly created resource group.

[image]

When I go to the newly created authoring instance in luis there is nothing there, because that isn't the authoring instance I initially used to write the bot and it says the managed identity is disabled.

[image]

[image]

And in Azure under in AzureBot/Properties where it says "luis app ids - view values as json" this is empty.

[image]

Is there a way to use the data from one luis instance (the instance that was used when the bot was written) and transfer that information to the newly created instance that Composer creates when publishing to Azure?

I ask these questions for the issues i'm having now, but also, in the future if I create a new bot in composer and set it up in luis - and then have Composer publish the new bot - it will create a separate luis authoring instance and i think i'll be in the same position as i am now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. At least with regards to provisioning. Composer *unfortunately* wasn't designed that way. Ideally the best way is to provision LUIS first and then utilize that authoring resource to author the LU and then publish when ready. Also; since your app is in the prediction resource, but nothing is in the authoring resource, you can export them from either the previous/working authoring resource or the prediction resource and import into the new authoring resource. Then you can then author and publish from there to prediction. Of course, this authoring would be for minor things like further training of intents.